# Laravel form won't PATCH, only POST - nested RESTfull Controllers, MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to allow **users** to edit their **playlist**. However, whenever I try to execute the PATCH request, I get the **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** error. (it is expecting a POST)

I have set up RESTful Resource Controllers:

Routes.php:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
Route::resource('users.playlists', 'PlaylistsController');
```

This should give me access to: (as displayed through *php artisan routes*)

```
URI                                        | Name                   | Action
PATCH users/{users}/playlists/{playlists}  | users.playlists.update | PlaylistsController@update
```

However, when I try to execute the following form, I get the **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** error:

/users/testuser/playlists/1/edit

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => ['users.playlists.update', $playlist->id], 'method' => 'PATCH' ]) }}
{{ Form::text('title', $playlist->title) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

If I remove `'method'=> 'PATCH'` I don't get an error, but it executes my `public function store()` and not my `public function update()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Laravel 5 and up:

```
<form method="POST" action="patchlink">
    @method('patch')
    . . .
</form>
```

Answer (score 14):

Write `{!! method_field('patch') !!}` after form:

```
<form method="POST" action="patchlink">
     {!! method_field('patch') !!}
     . . .
</form>
```

[Official documentation for helper function `method_field()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-method-field)

Answer (score 9):

Since html forms support only `GET` and `POST` you need to add an extra hidden field
to the form called `_method` in order to simulate a `PATCH` request

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
```

Comment: PATCH is being added via the method option in Form::open. You could also use PUT. I am having the same inexplicable issue, no matter what I do, the PUT or PATCH methods throw the MethodNotAllowedHttpException. Very frustrating.

Comment: Try with `Route::any('the_url_where_you_post_to', function(){});` or accordingly to the method you use `Route::patch` or `Route::put`

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by @Michael A in the comment above, send it as a POST

```
<form method="POST" action="patchlink">
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
```

Worked for me.