# Route [user.update] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i tried these two methods..

first one : MethodNotAllowedHttpException

`Route::post('/settings/{id}/update/', 'HomeController@update');`
`Route::match(['put','patch'], '/settings/{id}/update/','HomeController@update')`  use this also..

`{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'patch','action' => ['HomeController@update',$user->id]]) !!}`

another one

`{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'patch','route' => ['user.update',$user->id]]) !!}`

please explain how to use route for update default auth users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give a name to the route:

```
Route::patch('/settings/{id}/update/', 'HomeController@update')->name('user.update');
```

Or:

```
Route::patch('/settings/{id}/update/', ['as' => 'user.update', 'uses' => 'HomeController@update']);
```

Comment: once i remove the id parameter in HomeController's update function it entry the function..

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just be specific about the method you want to use, be it put or patch and also If i remember correctly, if you have to use patch method referencing the answer from this post: [Laravel form won't PATCH, only POST - nested RESTfull Controllers, MethodNotAllowedHttpException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857650/laravel-form-wont-patch-only-post-nested-restfull-controllers-methodnotallo)

```
<form method="POST" action="patchlink">
     {!! method_field('patch') !!}
     . . .
</form>
```

The method field is required because as I understood, Laravel uses this mechanism to handle patch request.

> PS: What I just tried to highlight if I understood correctly is that, there should be an extra field to handle the patch method.
>   Hope this helps :)

Comment: once i remove the id parameter in HomeController's update function it entry the function..